# TFS 2015 Build step Nuget Publisher "Ambiguous option 's'"

Tags: powershell, tfs, continuous-integration, nuget, tfs-2015

OK, so we're stuck on on-site TFS2015 at the moment. My Nuget Publisher build step is failing with:

```
##[error]Ambiguous option 's'. Possible values: Source SymbolSource SymbolApiKey.
```

[image: ##[error]Ambiguous option 's'. Possible values: Source SymbolSource SymbolApiKey.]

It appears inside the build step they have put -s instead of -source, and in later versions they've added more commands starting with s. So what are my options?

1. Write my own in Powershell (Can do, but TFS Build is very clunky for this)
2. Find wherever this is defined in TFS (hopefully a template .ps file) and fix it there (Anyone know where this is kept?)
3. Upgrade to a later version of TFS (a fairly large, but perhaps inevitable undertaking)
4. Somehow override the -s command another way?
5. ????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5. Invoke NuGet.exe however you'd like via the `Command Line` task

If you did #3 (upgrade TFS), you'd find that the PowerShell build task can run an in-line PowerShell script, making it significantly less clunky.

You may be able to extract and modify the task with the [`tfx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tfx-cli) command line utility, but I can almost guarantee this will have nasty ramifications when you do eventually upgrade.

Comment: Nice answer thanks, and I certainly was disappointed to see the lack of inline PS script. Unless anyone comes up with something more elegant I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: OK I accepted your answer, it was by far the simplest way. StackOverflow community delivers again! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my answer for details about step 5 maybe it will help team that are still using TFS 2015. 
Nuget Publisher seems to use old version, which means "-s" option will not work. 
To bypass this situation you can setup your build as follow:

1- Add Nuget Packager Step and specify the the **Package Folder value**:
[image: Package Folder value]

2- Add a new step which would copy your artifacts(Note that contents that should be copied must end with nupkg):

[image: Adding Copy Step for copying output]

3- And Finaly you can just run a command line that will perform the publish operation. In my case we are pushing the whole repository using init command(PackageRepository is the path to our internal feed that we set in we've set in Variables section):

[image]